# Paginate part of the content from page 2

Tags: frontend, pagination, paginate

I'm currently using pagination on a database site but I'm having trouble to paginate only part of the content for page 2.

Here is an example:

Index (page 1):

- Best products
- All Products (paginated content page 1)

Page 2:

- Best products (I don't want this here!)
- All Products (page 2)

How can I remove the "Best products" from page 2 when I'm paginating?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your front-end using twig, then please check the `pageInfo.currentPage` variable https://craftcms.com/docs/2.x/templating/paginate.html#the-pageinfo-variable

your final implementation would similar to

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('blog').limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

{% if pageInfo.currentPage == 1 %}
  {# render best products here #}
{% endif %}

{% for entry in pageEntries %}
  {# render item here #}
{% endfor %}

{# render pagination link here #}
```